# Cannot acess object in same package but different folder

Tags: java, object

I'm a little new to Java and I face a really awkward problem.
As you can see I have two Java files which are connected to each other(or at least they should be).
I have a "store" folder that contains the Store.java and it contains an "item" folder that has the Item.java in it.
When I try to make my List I get the error "cannot find symbol". I don't understand why it can't find the Item class.
Thanks for your help :)

Edit:My folder is like this:

//store//
- Store.java

- Store.class
- //item//
  (in the item folder down)

//item//

- Item.class
- Item.java

Store.java:

```
package store;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Store{
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Item.java:

```
package store.item;

public class Item{
    private String name;
    private int cost;

    public Item(String name, int cost){
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getCost(){
        return cost;
    }

    protected void setCost(int cost){
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not seem they are in the same package: `package store.item;` vs `package store;` Don't be tricked by the common beginning, these are still differenet packages.

Answer (score 0):

If by library you mean package, you have to import the Item class in Store :

```
import item.Item;
```

Comment: I wrote it pretty wrong. I meant folder (I edited it thanks).